# How to highlight a clicked portion of an image and display a description panel

Tags: android, android-image

I am trying to learn special effects in android. I want to add an image in my android application. When the user touch on particular portion of image, that portion should be highlighted and a description panel regarding that portion will be displayed (as displayed in the example). 
An example is posted here

[image]

Please suggest any method that can be used for implementing this effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a simple problem.

The simplest solution I'd suggest in to implement an [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) to get X and Y position of touch. Using its [MotionEvent getX() getY()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) values . Compare it to your portions position to know which one to highlight.

The effect of displaying highlights over portions can be achieve by placing invisible pictures on top of the main one (that represent only the highlighted portion in its highlight color on a transparent background, see what I mean?) And set them visible on user selection. The description panel can be included in this invisible image or be another invisible layout to set visible on selection (for example included in a [PopupWindow](http://android-er.blogspot.fr/2012/03/example-of-using-popupwindow.html) or so...)